# Usage of 'carved in stone'

Tags: expressions

I have always seen the expression 'carved in stone' used in the negative in sentences like: 'It is not carved in stone that..., Could this expression be used in the positive or, alternatively what other expression could I use to say that something is 'unchangeable' ?

Comment: Though 'not carved in stone' is very common, the original idiom is without the 'not' and has no negative connotations. http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/carved+in+stone

Comment: "We like to throw these labels around like they are black and white, carved in stone and not at all subject to interpretation or context."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A review of *carved in stone* in an [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=carved%20in%20stone&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,carved%20in%20stone;,c0) reveals mostly either literal usage (describing actual stonework) or negative usage.

There are occasional positive uses such as this description in *[Shark](http://books.google.com/books?id=4h8vrQzkG-IC&pg=PA191&dq=%22carved%20in%20stone%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EluQU4-IGu_IsATQ_ILADQ&ved=0CFUQ6AEwBjh4#v=onepage&q=%22carved%20in%20stone%22&f=false)*, Lauren St. John's biography of  Greg Norman

> He could not have been more confident of the outcome if it had been *carved in stone* beside the tee box.

A quote from Primo Levi about Holocaust survivors uses the phrase to indicate an indelible memory

> The survivors are divided into two well-defined groups: those who repress their past en bloc, and those whose memory of the offence persists, as though carved in stone.

The phrase forms the title of Manny Drukier's book, *[Carved in Stone: Holocaust Years, a Boy's Tale](http://books.google.com/books?id=Ac9tAAAAMAAJ&q=%22carved%20in%20stone%22&dq=%22carved%20in%20stone%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-12QU5T2K6zjsASrooGADw&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBQ)*

In *[Modern American Usage](http://books.google.com/books?id=KgVpvTpFgU8C&pg=PA284&dq=%22carved%20in%20stone%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kKSRU6PIMpHjsASD74GwCQ&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22carved%20in%20stone%22&f=false)*, the authors acknowledge the common negative connotation, while pointing out the availablity of the affirmative meaning

> Being democratic, we wish to accommodate others, hence the reassuring statement, always negative, that a particular rule, decision, or practice is not carved in stone; i.e., it can be changed. In the positive, the image comes quickly to mind: laboriously carving in the nearly indestructible stone.

Answer (score -1):

You can say that something is [*set in stone*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/set+in+stone) to indicate that a particular arrangement, document etc. cannot be changed. (Its opposite is, logically enough, *not set in stone*.)

> firmly established and very difficult to change | set in concrete